# OpenSSL error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: 18.04, phpmyadmin

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, `phpmyadmin` shows the below message:

```
OpenSSL error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

The system was fine before upgrading.

Comment: I'm having the same error.  I have the same config in Cent OS 7 and it works.  But with Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't.

Comment: Which is giving you this error? PHPMyAdmin, or Apache?  Typically this indicates that the configuration for the SSL has 'broken' in terms of how PMA connects to MySQL, and you would have to reconfigure the SSL on the backend.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin 4:4.6.6-5 running on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS I get also this error: `OpenSSL error: error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length`

Comment: check if the file format of your SSL certs is correct. Or maybe you have some copy/paste errors or even things like "^M" in there. What this error says is, that openssl cannot read your PEM files or cannot find the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"

Comment: I stand by my comment from 2019: openssl cannot read your PEM files